# expressionEngine prevent posting form from outside of page

Tags: expressionengine

I have a safecracker form with some hidden fields. I noticed if a user copy form source code  from browser view source, he can view the fields, fill the form and submit from outside the site.  How do we prevent this. I want post to only happen from the site and not from anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [Secure Forms Mode](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/spam_protection.html) enabled in your ExpressionEngine Control Panel?

> Secure Form Mode prevents automated scripts (the most common way spam is
>   generated) from repeatedly submitting comments or other form data. A
>   submission is only allowed when a user manually loads a page and submits the
>   form from your site. And once the form data is received, the user has to
>   manually reload the page before they can submit again.

The setting is located at: Admin > Security and Privacy > Security and Sessions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks great. Looking at this from a different point of view, if a person manipulates the DOM with firebug and changes the value in hidden fields then submits the form, wouldn't he be able to get away with it.

Comment: That's precisely what the [SafeSharpener Extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safesharpener/) for SafeCracker aims to address.